# what is "play" command/package available by default in Linux Mint and how to remove it

Tags: linux-mint, package-management, command

I'm trying install play framework on Linux Mint and setup its variable:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/relativePath/to/play
```

But command can't run because it's being overlapped by another **play** command which was installed in the system by default.

```
$ which play
/usr/bin/play
$ play --version
play:      SoX v14.4.1
```

These are definitely are not play framework related and I can't figure out how to remove this.

```
$ sudo apt-get remove play
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package play
```

It seems this command belongs to some package...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find out which package it belongs to by using `dpkg`:

```
dpkg -S /usr/bin/play
```

This will give you output that looks something like this:

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/sbin/sshd
openssh-server: /usr/sbin/sshd
```

If you have no use for this package, you can then remove that package with `apt-get remove`, or `apt-get purge` if you want to purge the configuration files, too.

If you instead get "no path found matching pattern", this file is not owned by any package, in which case you should carefully consider your options. You could remove it manually, but perhaps some installed package that was not installed by your package manager requires it.

You can also override the `play` binary that is called by putting your preferred binary at a location earlier in your `PATH`. To do that, you would invert the order of concatenation in your `export PATH` statement:

```
export PATH="/relativePath/to/play:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 6):

Your `play` command appears to be part of [`SoX`](http://sox.sourceforge.net/). That command plays audio files through the sound system. If you don't need it, then you have a few options:

- uninstall SoX
- adjust your `PATH` so `/relativePath/to/play` appears *before* `/usr/bin`
- remove or rename `/usr/bin/play` directly (but this could cause problems for your package manager, or it might simply reappear later if your package manager notices it's missing)

Answer (score 2):

The [`play`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/play) command is a de facto standard command on Linux. I don't recommend removing it: some applications may stop working properly. (Not in a very bad way, because `play` only plays sounds, but still.)

To see what the `play` command does, run `man play`.

To see what package the command belongs to, interrogate your package database. Since Mint uses dpkg as the packaging tool:

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/play
sox: /usr/bin/play
```

I don't recommend installing another command with the same name as a standard command, because it's a source of confusion. Nevertheless, if you want `play` to run the `play` command from Play Framework instead of the one from Sox, put the directory where it's located ahead of the standard directories on your command search path.

```
export PATH="/path/to/play-framework/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: I do not have `play` on my system, I have never had any applications fail because of its absence in all my years of running this system. I think qualifying it as a "de facto standard command" is perhaps a bit over the top.

Comment: In fact I have seen it being used in scripts in order to trigger "system" sounds